# Linux Document Management

Tags: search, software-rec, scanner, documents

I'm looking for a Linux (Freeware preferred) replacement for the Paperport Document Management Software by Nuance.

Wants: Scan to PDF.  OCR.  Simple Indexing and Searching.  Data stored locally. GUI.

Don't wants: Cloud Based, MySQL.

Most of what I am finding in my searches are business solutions (read expensive),  cloud storage and systems that require a MySQL or other database server (service?).

I've started using gscan2pdf.  My other want, something that will let me scan from the ADF off my HP Printer (Officejet 8600).

Comment: a sister site that you may find useful: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at paperwork: https://github.com/jflesch/paperwork
The repo says it has support for:

- scanning
- labelling and indexing
- OCR for label suggestion

As far as I can see, it uses local files for storage.